# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve property name hourtoreserve from Property set for bean com.ti.project.vaadin.vaadinprojectti.Day

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I am trying to print values from my database in simple vaadin UI. I was doing everything from this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/building-a-web-ui-for-mysql-databases-in-plain-java-

I changed it a little and I can't figure out why I can't set columns by myself. If I comment lines with setColumns and bindInstanceFields everything works but in the opposite order... In the other situation, I get the error mentioned in the title.

Here's the code:

Day Class:

```
package com.ti.project.vaadin.vaadinprojectti;

public class Day {
    private String hourToReserve;
    private String reservedOn;

    public Day(String hourToReserve, String reservedOn) {
        this.hourToReserve = hourToReserve;
        this.reservedOn = reservedOn;
    }

    public String getHourToReserve() {
        return hourToReserve;
    }

    public void setHourToReserve(String hourToReserve) {
        this.hourToReserve = hourToReserve;
    }

    public String getReservedOn() {
        return reservedOn;
    }

    public void setReservedOn(String reservedOn) {
        this.reservedOn = reservedOn;
    }
}
```

DayService Class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class DayService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Day> findAll(String dayName) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT hourtoreserve, reservedon FROM " + dayName,
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Day(
                        rs.getString("hourtoreserve"),
                        rs.getString("reservedon")));
    }

    public void update(Day day, String dayName){
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "UPDATE " + dayName + " SET reservedon=?",
                day.getReservedOn());
    }
}
```

and the Vaadin UI code, where the error occurs:

```
package com.ti.project.vaadin.vaadinprojectti;

import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@SpringUI
public class VaadinUI extends UI {

@Autowired
private DayService service;

private Day day;
private Binder<Day> binder = new Binder<>(Day.class);

private Grid<Day> grid = new Grid(Day.class);

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    updateGrid();

    grid.setColumns("hourtoreserve", "reservedon"); // if this is commented 
    binder.bindInstanceFields(this);           // it works but columns are in wrong order
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(grid);
    setContent(layout);
}

private void updateGrid() {
    List<Day> days = service.findAll("monday");
    grid.setItems(days);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem. It turned out that you need to put in grid.setColumns() method the exact variable names from class you bind! So in my case, it should be:

instead of:

```
 grid.setColumns("hourtoreserve", "reservedon")
```

it should be:

```
 grid.setColumns("hourToReserve", "reservedOn")
```

Comment: Indeed, Vaadin uses reflection to inspect your beans, so it would find the _houeToReserve_ property, not _hourtoreserve_.